# Error 3346, trying to INSERT INTO, two consecutive tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have those two tables is MS Access :

lkpSchemaPIT :

```
| UID |    lkpSchemaTitleEng     |  
|-----|--------------------------|  
|--1--|---------Title1-----------|  
|--2--|---------Title2-----------|
```

...

lkpSchemaPITChronology :

```
| ID | UID | PUID | Sort | Level | DateStart | DateEnd |  
|----|-----|------|------|-------|-----------|---------|  
|--0-|--1--|--0---|---5--|--2----|---Now()---|--NULL---|
```

...

The first table contains just nodes that i'm going to put in a treeview in access. I use the second table to construct the tree, but also keep track of all the parent that a node could've had through the years. You can see that the UID in the two tables are the same, but they have not a relationship between them, when I build the tree, I use a query with a join on it.

My problem is : When I want to add a new node in the lkpSchemaPIT table, I need to be able to add its "treeview" info as well (Parent, Sort, Level, etc.).
This is my code so far :

```vb
With CurrentDb
      .Execute _
        "INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPIT " & _
          "(lkpSchemaTitleEng) " & _
        "VALUES " & _
          "('" & Title & "')"
      .Execute _
        "INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPITChronology VALUES (" & .OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY").Fields(0) & ", " & [ParentID] & ", " & [NewSort] & ", " & [Level] & ", " & Date & ", null)"

End With
```

ParentID, NewSort, Level are 3 variables that have been determined before I call all this.
The "Date" parameters is the VBA function that returns the current date.

I know that the first INSERT INTO is working because a new value is displayed in my table. But the second INSERT INTO isn't working and I was able to get the error :

> Error 3346 - Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

Is anyone ever had this kind of problem ?

Comment: Start by specifying the columns you want to insert into in that last query. That often fixes it.

Comment: That changed the error that I'm getting : 3134 - Syntax Error in INSERT INTO.

Comment: Can you debug.print that string when it's filled in and causing the error?

Comment: That's what I got : INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPITChronology (UID, PUID, Sort, Level, DateStart)VALUES (104, 19, 5, 2, 2018-02-15)

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, changed it, but nothing changes.

Comment: Ah I think I see it, your date needs to be formatted. I believe access uses # for date delimiters.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to cause this exact error, but SQL evaluates `2018-02-15` to the number _2001_, cast that to a date and you get `23-06-1905`. I'd add octothorpes around that date.

Comment: I've added # around my date, which gave me this result for the debug.print : 
INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPITChronology ( UID, PUID, Sort, Level, DateStart)  VALUES (113, 19, 5, 2, #2018-02-15#); And I still have the same error (Syntax Error)

Comment: `Level` is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx), use `[Level]`.

Comment: Did it, no changes and same syntax error :  INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPITChronology ( UID, PUID, Sort, Level, DateStart ) VALUES (116, 19, 5, 2, #2018-02-15#)

Comment: Where are the square brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, here is an example where parameterized queries would be invaluable as you avoid quote enclosures (including `#` for date/times) and string concatenation that conflates data and SQL together, rendering hard to read and maintain code.

MS Access allows the `PARAMETERS` clause where you can define the parameter placeholder names and data types and then in VBA you can bind values to such parameters using [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx). No quotes needed or string interpolation.

**SQL** *(save both as stored queries)*

```sql
PARAMETERS TitleParam Text(255);
INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPIT (lkpSchemaTitleEng)
VALUES (TitleParam);

PARAMETERS UIDParam Long, PUIDParam Long, SortParam Long, 
           LevelParam Long, DateStart Datetime;
INSERT INTO lkpSchemaPITChronology (UID, PUID, [Sort], [Level], DateStart)
VALUES (UIDParam, PUIDParam, SortParam, LevelParam, DateStartParam);
```

**VBA**

```vb
...
Dim qdef As QueryDef

With CurrentDb

   ' FIRST QUERY
   Set qdef = .QueryDefs("myFirstSavedAppendQuery")

   qdef!TitleParam = [Title]
   qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

   ' SECOND QUERY
   Set qdef = .QueryDefs("mySecondSavedAppendQuery")

   qdef!UIDParam = .OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY").Fields(0)
   qdef!PUIDParam = [ParentID]
   qdef!SortParam = [NewSort]
   qdef!LevelParam = [Level]
   qdef!DateStart = Date()

   qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

End With

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: Great! And do note: parameterization is an industry best practice recommended in other languages when working with SQL: Java, C#, Python, PHP, etc.