# Why does this SQL query work in query designer but not in VBA for Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

When I execute the following two queries in Create > Query one after the other they work perfectly. When I attempt to execute the queries in VBA only the first one (invoiceline) works.

I know for a fact it is not the query itself that is the problem, it is the way that I am perhaps establishing the connection. I get the error invalid lexical when attempting to execute the query.

**When pressing a button this query is executed correctly**

buttonOne_Click()

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3


Dim oConnection
Dim oRecordset
Dim sMsg
Dim sConnectString
Dim sSQL
sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"

sSQL = "INSERT INTO InvoiceLine (InvoiceLineItemRefListID, InvoiceLineDesc, InvoiceLineRate, InvoiceLineAmount, InvoiceLineSalesTaxCodeRefListID, FQSaveToCache) VALUES ('80002436-1519061496', 'Building permit 1', 1.00000, 1.00, '80000001-1478562826', 1)"

Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConnection.Open sConnectString
oConnection.Execute (sSQL)
sMsg = sMsg & "Invoice details were gathered!"
MsgBox sMsg

End Sub
```

**This one fails with error**

buttonTwo_Click()

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3


Dim oConnection
Dim oRecordset
Dim sMsg
Dim sConnectString
Dim sSQL




sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"

sSQL = "INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerRefListID, ARAccountRefListID, TxnDate, RefNumber, BillAddressAddr1, BillAddressAddr2, BillAddressCity, BillAddressState, BillAddressPostalCode, BillAddressCountry, IsPending, TermsRefListID, DueDate, ShipDate, ItemSalesTaxRefListID, Memo, IsToBePrinted, CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefListID) VALUES ('800001F6-1482536280', '8000001E-1478562986', #9/23/2020#, '1', 'Brad Lamb', '1921 Appleseed Lane', 'Bayshore', 'CA', '94326', 'USA', 0, '80000002-1478562832', #10/31/2020#, #10/01/2020#, '8000295C-1541711590', 'Memo Test', 0, '80000001-1478562826')"


Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConnection.Open sConnectString
oConnection.Execute (sSQL)
sMsg = sMsg & "Invoice was Sent to QuickBooks"
MsgBox sMsg

End Sub
```

The second one relies on the first one to finish, once again both queries work perfectly in the Query designer in Microsoft Access, but the second one fails when running in VBA SQL in a macro or procedure.

This is the error I see:

Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':

[QODBC] [sql syntax error] Expected lexical element not found: =)

**UPDATE**

I have tried all of these with no luck, any other suggestions?

01-10-2005

2005-01-10

01/10/2005

2005/01/10

Comment: `#9/23/2020#` is not valid SQL.

Comment: Take the SQL over to SSMS and try to submit it directly to your SQL Server instance. You should get better diagnostics.

Comment: @Corion what is the proper way to submit the date ? Instead of using " # " ?

Comment: Most likely `'2020-09-23'`, but that depends on your database settings.

Comment: Here's what doesn't make sense to me, why do these queries work in Create > Query ?

Comment: When run through the query window Access will use it's interpreter to handle the dates the correct way, when invoked in VBA you are passing the query directly to the ODBC connection which doesn't understand the Access syntax.

Comment: @Minty I see, I can’t seem to find how QODBC wants the dates formatted

Comment: Please take a look at my update

Comment: @Corion #9/23/2020# is correct ACCESS SQL usage for dates. The use of "# # " is how you indicate dates in Access.

Comment: @Karlomanio Yes its the right Access SQL usage but the wrong syntax  for QODBC

Comment: Can you link to the Quickbooks tables? If so what data type does access think the date columns are? They maybe text bizarrely. Accounts packages are weird...

Comment: Did you use single quotes around your date attempts? `'01-10-2005'`, not `01-10-2005`

Comment: I looked in the linked table for invoice and the column for txnDate just shows the " mm/dd/yyyy " format

Comment: @Corion Yes single quotes

Comment: While I dont have any clue of qodbc, if you dont have all the fields as required, try running a minimal insert statements living other fields as null and add fields to the statement one by one to see what field is causing the problem? Is `memo` a reserved word?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read here https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2638/44/qodbc-desktop-troubleshooting---how-to-use-date-and-dateadd-function-in-qodbc

The correct format appears to be {d 'YYYY-MM-DD'} 
There is a function provided to make a date the correct string;

Function:

```
Function fncqbDate(myDate As Date) As String
myDate = Nz(myDate, Now)
fncqbDate = "{d '" & Year(myDate) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(myDate), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Day(myDate), 2) & "'}"
End Function
```

Comment: Simply use `Format`: `Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")`

Comment: I just tried to submit the date as , {d'2005-09-23'},

Comment: Still no luck, same issue

Comment: Note there is a space between the d and the '

Comment: The problem is still the same, but quick side question, is it correct to have two separate sSQL = " " query statements for queries that are related? Or could have the two query statements under the same sSQL= " " ?

Comment: No you are inserting data into two separate tables, so that requires two queries.

Answer (score 1):

As @Minty commented and posted, your dates are the issue.

- When running queries inside the MS Access GUI such as with Query Designer, you are governed to the Access SQL dialect.
- When connecting via ODBC driver to an external database, you are governed to the connecting database's SQL dialect, here being Quickbooks.

No two SQL dialects are ever the same but most attempt to conform to ANSI standards. Therefore, the same queries *can* fail between Query Designer and VBA.

### MS Access

MS Access dates if sent literally, should be encapsulated with hashtags, `#`:

```sql
INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerRefListID, ARAccountRefListID, TxnDate, RefNumber,
                     BillAddressAddr1, BillAddressAddr2, BillAddressCity, BillAddressState, 
                     BillAddressPostalCode, BillAddressCountry, IsPending, TermsRefListID, 
                     DueDate, ShipDate, ItemSalesTaxRefListID, [Memo], IsToBePrinted, 
                     CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefListID) 
VALUES ('800001F6-1482536280', '8000001E-1478562986', #9/23/2020#, '1', 'Brad Lamb', 
        '1921 Appleseed Lane', 'Bayshore', 'CA', '94326', 'USA', 0, '80000002-1478562832', 
         #10/31/2020#, #10/01/2020#, '8000295C-1541711590', 
         'Memo Test', 0, '80000001-1478562826')
```

Alternatively, use `CDate()` to convert string to date:

```sql
INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerRefListID, ARAccountRefListID, TxnDate, RefNumber,
                     BillAddressAddr1, BillAddressAddr2, BillAddressCity, BillAddressState, 
                     BillAddressPostalCode, BillAddressCountry, IsPending, TermsRefListID, 
                     DueDate, ShipDate, ItemSalesTaxRefListID, [Memo], IsToBePrinted, 
                     CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefListID) 
VALUES ('800001F6-1482536280', '8000001E-1478562986', CDate('9/23/2020'), '1', 'Brad Lamb', 
        '1921 Appleseed Lane', 'Bayshore', 'CA', '94326', 'USA', 0, '80000002-1478562832', 
        CDate('10/31/2020'), CDate('10/01/2020'), '8000295C-1541711590', 
        'Memo Test', 0, '80000001-1478562826')
```

---

### Quickbooks ODBC

In Quickbooks, you must adhere to its date requirement of `{d 'YYYY-MM-DD'}` or  the functional form `fncqbDate()`. However, documentation on these methods is sparse to non-existent and can vary with ODBC driver versions.

```vb
sql = "INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerRefListID, ARAccountRefListID, TxnDate, RefNumber, " _
       & "                  BillAddressAddr1, BillAddressAddr2, BillAddressCity,  " _
       & "                  BillAddressState, BillAddressPostalCode, BillAddressCountry,  " _
       & "                  IsPending, TermsRefListID, DueDate, ShipDate,  " _
       & "                  ItemSalesTaxRefListID, [Memo], IsToBePrinted,  " _
       & "                  CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefListID)  " _
       & " VALUES ('800001F6-1482536280', '8000001E-1478562986', {d '2020-09-23'}, '1',  " _
       & "         'Brad Lamb', '1921 Appleseed Lane', 'Bayshore', 'CA', '94326', 'USA', 0,  " _ 
       & "         '80000002-1478562832', {d '2020-10-31'}, {d '2020-10-01'},  " _
       & "         '8000295C-1541711590', 'Memo Test', 0, '80000001-1478562826')"
```

---

### Parameterization

With that said, even if above does not work, this is yet another good reason for parameterization, a programming industry standard for any application layer like VBA to run SQL. Parameterization facilitates data type mapping between client and server without the need of quote or other symbolic closures. ADO does support parameters with [CreateParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017) method inside an [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017) object (not ADO recordset).

```vb
' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PLACEHOLDERS (NO LITERAL DATA)
sql = "INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerRefListID, ARAccountRefListID, TxnDate, RefNumber, " _
       & "                  BillAddressAddr1, BillAddressAddr2, BillAddressCity,  " _
       & "                  BillAddressState, BillAddressPostalCode, BillAddressCountry,  " _
       & "                  IsPending, TermsRefListID, DueDate, ShipDate,  " _
       & "                  ItemSalesTaxRefListID, [Memo], IsToBePrinted,  " _
       & "                  CustomerSalesTaxCodeRefListID)  " _
       & " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?," _ 
       & "         ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

' OPEN CONNECTION
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")   
oConnection.Open sConnectString

' INITIALIZE AND RUN COMMAND
Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")              ' NEW ADO OBJECT
With oCmd
   .ActiveConnection = oConnection
   .CommandText = sql
   .CommandType = adCmdText

   ' BIND PARAMETERS
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm1", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"800001F6-1482536280")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm2", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"8000001E-1478562986") 
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm3", adDate, adParamInput, , CDate("9/23/2020"), 
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm4", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"1") 
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm5", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"Brad Lamb")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm6", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"1921 Appleseed Lane")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm7", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"Bayshore")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm8", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"CA")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm9", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"94326")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm10", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"USA")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm11", adInteger, adParamInput, , 0)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm12", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"80000002-1478562832")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm13", adDate, adParamInput, , CDate("10/31/2020"))
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm14", adDate, adParamInput, , CDate("10/01/2020")) 
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm15", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"8000295C-1541711590")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm16", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"Memo Test")
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm17", adInteger, adParamInput, ,0)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm18", adVarChar, adParamInput, ,"80000001-1478562826")

   ' RUN PARAMETERIZED QUERY
   .Execute
End With

oConnection.Close
Set oCmd = Nothing: Set oConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: Ok so I tried your code right under "Quickbooks ODBC" it seemed to work because now I get a different error: [QODBC] Not supported - At least one Line record is required. Please insert Child/Detail record(s) before inserting Parent/Header record. For more details please visit:godbc.comilinks/2953 "

Comment: The issue is that InvoiceLine, the first piece of code I posted is the child its looking for

Comment: I know for a fact that both should work because once again it did in Query Designer

Comment: Usually, the parent table rows are inserted before related children as this appears to be a relationships issue in Quickbooks. Did you go to their url: https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2953/? Like the Query Designer runs, you will also need to run both append queries but think carefully the order. Possibly too this query relates to other tables like *Customer* (which should exist prior to *Invoice*). Even more, your earlier test runs may invalidate next test runs since keys may need to be unique. Try testing on new invoice example.

Comment: It should just append itself once the first query runs, right?

Comment: Unless Quickbooks has triggers set in place for the two tables to connect then yes. Nonetheless, your immediate issue of queries not working should be resolved, right? *I know for a fact that both should work because once again it did in Query Designer* ... once again, you used a *different* engine to make the *same* SQL command and SQL dialects differ in engines (German <> English even if both say the same thing!). The beauty of parameterization is no matter what the data types or database, you abstract away dialect specific escapes or formatting. Please consider the last option.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Access application, I would recommend that instead of rewriting the query into sql/vba code to instead take another approach:  leave the working query as a query object and instead use vba to trigger it:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName"
```

This has the advantage of having that query object existing in the navigation pane so that you can run it manually for testing - without having to run any vba.  It is a much simpler debug strategy.

Comment: I’d consider that, but I also using a form with text boxes for input in the query. The code I am using in my post includes only static inputs I have made up for the example. Can what you are proposing also include inputs from a form?

Comment: @RichardWalton, you can point values in a saved query to form controls: `Forms!myForm!mycontrol` (no quotes or other enclosures). Then call `DoCmd.OpenQuery`. Alternatively, you can pass parameters to a saved query using [QueryDefs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810100/1422451) but this uses DAO (not ADO) implementation. Finally, you can use ADO as I proposed above, passing dynamic values into `CreateParameter` calls (last argument). Did you attempt this? StackOverflow has many, many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+parameterization) on SQL parameterization in VBA.

Comment: @Parfait I got the saved query to work, is there a way to make the all of the prompts that appear, auto accept (press yes on its own)?

Comment: It should not prompt you if the form is open to screen for controls to be available by query. If form is open, then you mis-typed the absolute form control path. Do note subforms have different paths. Consider bookmarking this page: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm (do not use `Me.`, the relative reference). And remember no quotes, hashtags, or other enclosures.